# \noindent is not working withing \title

Tags: titles, indentation

I am making a bilingual document, where the text is in one main language, and then on each line after, in English translation, which should be in italics. It works fine, expect for the title, where the English text is indented, despite the fact that I use \noindent. \noindent works as expected elsewhere in the document.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\title{SVENSKA\newline\noindent\textit{ENGLISH}}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent{Lite text}\newline\textit{Some text}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image showing how \noindent isn't working in \title]

Comment: Use ``\\`` instead of `\newline`; remove `\noindent`, because it does nothing at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and forget about the existence of `\newline`. `;-)`

A place where it doesn't work is precisely a `center` environment, which is internally used by `\maketitle`.

Use `\\`.

Here's an example showing that the problem is in `center`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{SVENSKA \\ \textit{ENGLISH}}
\author{}
\date{}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\newline
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

\bigskip

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]